# Замедление httpwebrequest после 30 минут запросов

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, websocket, httpwebrequest

В моем решении я произвожу множество httpwebrequest через proxy сервер. На протяжении 30 минут скорость получение возрастает до 6-10 ответов в секунду, после чего скорость начинает постепенно падать. При отладке видно что скорость получения данных от прокси (httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) растет вплоть до 15-20 секунд. В то время как при параллельном использовании этого же прокси-сервера в браузере, на этом же ресурсе, я получаю ответ меньше чем за секунду. 
Я пробовал менять:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit, 
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime, 
httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout,
httpWebRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering,
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive.
```

Это не принесло никаких результатов.

Так же я заметил средствами Tcpview что в браузере разрыв tcp соединения проискодит более чем за 60 секунд. В то время как в моем приложении этот же процесс происходит в течении порядка 10 секунд. Я подозреваю что скорее всего проблема в этом. 
Я уверен здесь есть знающие люди которые могут подсказать в чем может быть проблема.

Решение написано на C# тестируется на Windows server 2012 используется net framework 4.5